# No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Sorry to ask this ! I'm newbie so feel free to teach me anything you guys know.
I'm making a scraping tool for my marketing purpose to scrape contact information from website. I'm using Python 3
This is my code:

```
import requests, bs4, os, codecs, csv
import pandas as pd
import sys

os.path.join('usr', 'bin', 'spam')
openFile = open('C:\\Users\\hdtra\\Desktop\\Test_1.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig')

read_test = csv.reader(openFile)


for link in read_test :
    res = requests.get(link)
    res.raise_for_status
    facebookSpider = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
    email = facebookSpider.select("._4-u2._3xaf._3-95._4-u8")
    helloFile = open('C:\\Users\\hdtra\\Desktop\\In processing\\information.txt','w')
    helloFile.write(str(email[3].encode('utf-8')) + '\n')
    helloFile.close()
```

Have no idea why it gets me st like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\hdtra\Desktop\In processing\Facebook_spider.py", line 12, in <module>
     res = requests.get(link)
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 612, in send
     adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in get_adapter
     raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url) 
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['http://www.facebook.com/D2Streetwear/?ref=br_rs']'
```

I know that `get()` only gets string, but have no idea how to convert these links into strings. This is my cvs file:

only one column with 5 row:

```
http://www.facebook.com/D2Streetwear/?ref=br_rs
https://www.facebook.com/RealClothes/?ref=br_rs
https://www.facebook.com/Lecamelliaclothing/?ref=br_rs
https://www.facebook.com/TaTclothing-285844471884952/?ref=br_rs
https://www.facebook.com/Dai-Clothing-130675847640538/?ref=br_rs
```

I tried to put `str(link())` but it does not work.

Comment: `reader` returns a list of lists. You'll need to index the 0th column: `link[0]`

Comment: can you show me how to do it ?

Comment: you already got how to do it - use `link[0]` instead of `link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand that [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) returns an iterator that iterates over each row to return a list of columns for each one.

> ## `csv`.`reader`(`csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams`)
>
> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given
> `csvfile`.[...]
> **Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.**

Bold emphasis mine. Your CSV appears to contain a single column, so you can access the first column using `link[0]`.

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)

    for row in r:
        r = requests.get(row[0])
        ...
```

I consider it good practice to always use a `with...as` context manager when handling file I/O, as it automatically closes your file and results in cleaner code.